# Why this inequality holds?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

I see this in my class note. I know the first one comes form the Euler's formula, but I really don't know the reason why the last inequality holds?

$|(e^{-ix_jt}-1)/t|=|(\cos(x_jt)-\cos0)/t-i(\sin(x_jt)-\sin0)/t|\le 2|x_j|$

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Mean Value Theorem there exist c,d so that

$$\left| \frac{\cos(x_jt)-\cos(0)}{x_jt-0} \right|= \left| \cos'(c) \right| \leq 1$$

$$\left| \frac{\sin(x_jt)-\sin(0)}{x_jt-0} \right|= \left| \sin'(d) \right| \leq 1$$